# GZIP WCF 4.5 Setting up and testing

Tags: c#, wcf, gzip

I'm having difficulty finding documentation that makes sense when trying to implement gzip.

I've created a new wcf service with a method that returns a list of integers for testing.

The web.config looks like so

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="TestWCF.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehaviour">
    <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="cbCompression" contract="TestWCF.ITestService" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="cbCompression">
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="cbCompression" >
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="defaultBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can use the WCF Test client to call the service but was expecting to see compressed data. Instead I see a list of integers.

I therefore don't know if gzip is compressing my data in the response or if I have the config set up incorrectly.

Help would be appreciated. Other stack questions haven't touched on testing results.